# android - download audio to app cache directory and then play

Tags: android, caching, audio, download, media

In a nutshell, I have a button that should either download audiofile from direct url to the private app cache directory, or (if it was previously done) play that file from cache.

How can I solve it? Could you provide some examples, please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to download the file and save the path either in a Preference (recommended if you will only have one or just a couple files) or in a database (ideal if a lot of files).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) you can find a cool guide on how to download a file and save it. Also have a look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) from the official docs to know better how to save a file properly.

Once you save it you save the path to your file in one of the ways suggested before and play it like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(path);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Take a look to [this article](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) in the docs for further information.